# How to Change the Color Back Button in Ioinc2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I search for a way to change the color of the text and find this code but it did not work

```
ion-header ion-icon.back-button-icon.icon {
color: map-get($colors, dark) !important;
}


.md,
.wp {.back-button {color: red !important;}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
.bar-button-default-ios, .bar-button-default.bar-button-ios-default, .bar-button-clear-ios-default {
  color: map-get($colors, dark) !important;
}

.bar-button-default-md, .bar-button-default.bar-button-md-default, .bar-button-clear-md-default {
  color: map-get($colors, dark) !important;
}

.bar-button-default-wp, .bar-button-default.bar-button-wp-default, .bar-button-clear-wp-default {
  color: map-get($colors, dark) !important;
}
```